# react.js change parent width based on child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have created a `NavigationBar` component using [`react-bootstrap`](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/), so that I can use that over and over in my project.

[`NavigationBar`](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Local-File-Server/blob/master/local_file_server/src/component/NavigationBar.js):

```html
<div>
  <NotificationContainer />
  <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
    <Navbar.Brand href="/home">Local File Server</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end" />
    <Form inline>
      <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className=" mr-sm-2" />
      <Button type="submit">Search</Button>
      <Button variant="danger" type="submit" href="/upload">
        Upload
      </Button>
    </Form>
  </Navbar>
</div>;
```

Which works fine :

[image]

Until, table gets populated and horizontal scrollbar appears. Then I miss the complete navigation bar, like this :

[image]

How can I resolve this ?

[`Home.js`](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Local-File-Server/blob/master/local_file_server/src/component/Home.js#L80)

components : https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Local-File-Server/tree/master/local_file_server/src/component

Comment: Use some css of your own?

Comment: @Saurav, not in navbar or i used [one](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Local-File-Server/blob/master/local_file_server/src/index.css#L1) in whole page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way from the internet, by passing a callback function to the child as props.

Answer (score 1):

I think that adding "responsive" to Table props is the easiest fix

```
 <Table striped bordered hover responsive>
```

Comment: although it is not the correct solution, still it somewhat fixed the problem, as it changed the width of the table and added a scroll-bar on it, didn't change the navbar actually

Comment: I think that in terms of UX/UI it's on of 2 solutions and the second one is to change the layout of table into single column on smaller screens using breakpoints. Nobody likes to scroll horizontally trying to find navbar button that went far to the right side because of wide table :)

Comment: that's actually a nice thing, but the fact is it is going to be used on a 48 inch wide monitor, and I'm also trying a bot(chrome extension) that will automatically scroll in both direction... so that would work better for me, now I need to modify that bot, in order to get it working with current situation.. which I have done.. :p